# R: Euclidian distances between objects in a group

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I want to create a matrix with similarities based on two identifiers, consider following matrix:

```
x1  <- c(2,2,2,3,1,2,4,6,4)
y1  <- c(5,4,3,3,4,2,1,6,3)
x2  <- c(8,2,7,3,1,2,2,2,6)
y2  <- c(1,3,3,3,1,2,4,3,8)
x3  <- c(4,4,1,2,4,6,3,2,9)
y3  <- c(1,2,3,3,1,2,4,6,1)
id1 <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b")
id2 <- c(2002,2002,2003,2003,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003)
dat <- data.frame(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,id1,id2)
```

For the groups marked by `id1` and `id2` I want to create the euclidean distance `(sqrt((x1a-x1b)^2+(y1a-y1b)^2 + ... + (y3a-y3b)^2))` between the lines in the dataset. In the best case, there would be a new variable that indicates the distances of each line to each other line with the same `id1` and `id2`. Please note that different numbers of members can be in each group as for instance in 2003 in the b-group there are three cases. 
Any advice would be great!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea first to distinguish the lines whose distances you want to calculate. For example, for id1 == b and id2 == 2003 you have 3 lines, and you want to calculate 3 different distances (between each possible pair). So let's first assign each of these a unique id.

```
f <- function(n) {
    # Returns a vector 
    # 1, 2, 1, 3, ..., 1, n, 2, 3, 2, 4, ..., 2, n, ..., (n-1), n
    m <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n * (n-1) / 2)
    m[, 1] <- rep(1:(n-1), (n-1):1)
    m[, 2] <- unlist(lapply(2:n, function(x) x:n))
    as.numeric(t(m))
}
# Alternatively,
# f <- function(n) {
#     d <- expand.grid(a = 1:n, b = 1:n)
#     d <- d[d$a < d$b, ]
#     unlist(d)
# }
# but this is slower



# Using plyr...
library(plyr)
dat <- ddply(dat, .(id1, id2), function(d) {
    d <- d[f(nrow(d)), ]
    d$id3 <- paste0(d$id1, rep(1:(nrow(d) / 2), each = 2))
    d
})

# ...or using base R
dat <- do.call(rbind, 
     by(dat, list(dat$id1, dat$id2), function(d) {
     d <- d[f(nrow(d)), ]
     d$id3 <- paste0(d$id1, rep(1:(nrow(d) / 2), each = 2))
     d
}))
```

Now there will only be two lines for each (id3, id2) pair and you can calculate the differences as follows

```
# Using plyr
result <- ddply(dat, .(id3, id2), function(d) {
    d <- d[paste0(rep(c("x", "y"), 3), 1:3)]
    d$dist <- sqrt(sum((d[1, ] - d[2, ])^2))
    d
})

# Base R
result <- do.call(rbind, 
    by(dat[paste0(rep(c("x", "y"), 3), 1:3)],
        list(dat$id3, dat$id2), 
        function(d){
            d$dist <- sqrt(sum((d[1, ] - d[2, ])^2))
            d
        }
))
result[c("id3", "id2")] <- dat[c("id3", "id2")]
result
#     x1 y2 x3 y1 x2 y3      dist id3  id2
# 1    2  1  4  5  8  1  6.480741  a1 2002
# 2    2  3  4  4  2  2  6.480741  a1 2002
# 5    1  1  4  4  1  1  3.464102  b1 2002
# 6    2  2  6  2  2  2  3.464102  b1 2002
# 3    2  3  1  3  7  3  4.242641  a1 2003
# 4    3  3  2  3  3  3  4.242641  a1 2003
# 7    4  4  3  1  2  4  5.916080  b1 2003
# 8    6  3  2  6  2  6  5.916080  b1 2003
# 7.1  4  4  3  1  2  4  9.000000  b2 2003
# 9    4  8  9  3  6  1  9.000000  b2 2003
# 8.1  6  3  2  6  2  6 11.313708  b3 2003
# 9.1  4  8  9  3  6  1 11.313708  b3 2003
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the code works, but I would like to have the distances for the cases WITHIN one group and simulatneously WITHIN year

Comment: I was somehow confused by the terms like y3a-y3b in the OP, which lead me to believe you wanted distance between groups a and b... I think I now understand what you want to do, let me know if it works...

Comment: This looks quite good already, konvas and works perfectly for groups that have two people only. However for the group with three (that was the last, 2003, b), there is only one value. It would be great to have the distances between each line, with each other line of the group. So, each of the values would be ideally assigned two distances in this group - I am sorry for unclarities

Comment: thanks!! this helps already alot, last question, can we move this to columns instead of new rows? thanks so much already

Comment: no problem! you mean have extra columns for b1, b2, b3 instead of new rows? I don't think that would work because then the data corresponding to id1 == "a" would have fewer columns than that with id1 == "b", so you couldn't rbind them.. The easiest is probably to reshape the final data frame in the format that you want (using base R `reshape()` or `dcast()` from package `reshape2` or `spread` from `tidyr`)

Comment: and how do i know which original group the values stem from - e.g., id1? sorry, again!

Comment: Well it is the non-numeric part of id3, but you can also keep the column id1 of the original data frame (which is why I created id3 instead of overwriting id1). If you print dat$id1 you will see it's still there..

Comment: ok thank you so much, it works - however, my dataset seems to be to big. :( cannot allocate xxx mb. Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: no problem, you can always divide your data into subsets (e.g. one subset for each year) and then run the code on these...

Comment: i openend another question for a different problem. I tried a bit further with the dist() function. again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be helpful.

dist(dat[which(dat[,"id1"]=="a" & dat[,"id2"]=="2002"),], method ="euclidean")
dist(dat[which(dat[,"id1"]=="b" & dat[,"id2"]=="2003"),], method ="euclidean")

Comment: The results below are different when comparing with dist() function. I am a bit confused as well. When you have more than 2 element in a group which distance you prefer do display in a new column and in the same row of element? For instance b-group 2003?

Comment: there should be 2 values, so a distance matrix. dist(x, upper=TRUE) might useful, I just found it. But I have no clue how to loop over the groups and to get a matrix with the same number of columns then ... i.e. I am not sure how to attach the columns to the dataset

Comment: > dat$new=NULL
> for (i in 1:length(dat)){
+   dat$new[i]=i
+ }

Comment: perhaps this will help

Comment: not sure, how? (sorry for the inconvenience and great thanks for the help!